# Numerical Integration of MeijerG function in the form MeijerG[{{-2,-8.5,-3.5},{}},{{0},{-1.5}},theta]

Tags: numerical-integration

When I evaluate

```
a = MeijerG[{{-2, -8.5, -3. 5}, {}}, {{0}, {-1.5}}, theta] 
NItegrate[a, {theta, 0, Pi/2}]
```

and allow the evaluation to run even for a day. it's not giving any output.

Can anyone help me to find what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

The trick seems to be to [`FunctionExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html) the [`MeijerG`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeijerG.html) function before integration:

```
a[θ_] = MeijerG[{{-2, -17/2, -7/2}, {}}, {{0}, {-3/2}}, θ] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify
(*    (Sqrt[π] Sqrt[θ] (128 + θ (4416 + θ (50048 + θ (213120 - 7 θ (-36608 + 3 θ (3168 + 5 θ (-432 + θ (400 + 9 θ (-40 + θ (18 + 11 θ)))))))))) -
      32 E^(1/θ) π (4 + 7 θ (20 + θ (233 + 34 θ (31 + 45 θ)))) Erfc[1/Sqrt[θ]])/(128 θ^(27/2))    *)

Integrate[a[θ], {θ, 0, π/2}]
(*    (1/(1024 π^(21/2)))(-2097152 - 24117248 π - 78643200 π^2 - 65601536 π^3 + 9732096 π^4 - 3870720 π^5 + 2150400 π^6 - 1209600 π^7 + 362880 π^8 + 166320 π^9 + 30405375 π^11 + 262144 Sqrt[2] E^(2/π) (8 + π (94 + 7 π (46 + 45 π))) Erfc[Sqrt[2/π]])    *)

% // N
(*    52664.9    *)
```

Comment: Sir, may I know what kind of conversion you did in the above answer?

Comment: Seems a regression in higher versions. Version 8.0 gives an immediate answer and no error message   `(1/(1024 \[Pi]^(
 21/2)))(-2097152 - 24117248 \[Pi] - 78643200 \[Pi]^2 - 
  65601536 \[Pi]^3 + 9732096 \[Pi]^4 - 3870720 \[Pi]^5 + 
  2150400 \[Pi]^6 - 1209600 \[Pi]^7 + 362880 \[Pi]^8 + 
  166320 \[Pi]^9 + 30405375 \[Pi]^11 + 
  262144 Sqrt[2] E^(
   2/\[Pi]) (8 + \[Pi] (94 + 7 \[Pi] (46 + 45 \[Pi]))) Erfc[Sqrt[
    2/\[Pi]]]) ` , which is `52664.9 ` .

Comment: @kirubakaran I replaced numerical-precision numbers like `8.5` by exact rationals like `17/2` and then used analytic instead of numerical integration.

Comment: @Akku14I am using mathematica 9. Mathematica 8 is also not available online. Any idea brother?

Comment: @Roman Sir, First I did FuctionExpand like this, a[theta_] = 
 FunctionExpand[
  MeijerG[{{-(q13 + q1 + q2 + (2*mu) + p - 1), 
     1 - (q13 + q1 + qi1 + mu + p + (L*mu)), 
     1 - (q13 + q1 + mu + p)}, {}}, {{0}, {-(q13 + q1 + mu + p)}}, 
   C1/(BI*gammak1*(Bsd + ((Sin[Pi/M]^2)/(Sin[theta]^2))))]] then i integrate that, now also its taking time, but not giving the solution, Sir.

Comment: Well that's a much more complicated problem, @kirubakaran. Maybe ask it as a separate question?

Comment: actually this is also same, here I included the variable, instead of numbers. okay, I'll ask in a separate question.

Comment: @Roman Sir, I posted the above comment as a separate question, can you answer that?